# Trying to combine a VBA copy/paste loop with a VBA 'Open File' Dialog Box

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel macro that copies and pastes line items from a source file to an Excel-based form. It opens a form template and saves each line item as it's own file then loops through the remaining rows. Right now I have a file path built into the code that refers to the form template needed, but I need the user to be able to choose which file they want to use as their template. I have code for both of these processes but I haven't been able to combine them. My example below results in a Compile Error: Variable not defined.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToForm()

Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbForm As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsForm As Worksheet
Dim formpath As String, foldertosavepath As String
Dim lrow As Long, i As Integer

Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook '~~> Write your code in Indication Tool.xls
Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Indication Tool") '~~> Put the source sheet name

'~~> This opens the Processing Form template.
formpath = "C:\File path.xls"


'~~> Prompts user with Open File Dialog Box
strCancel = "N"
strWorkbookNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:=strFilt, _
     FilterIndex:=intFilterIndex, _
     Title:=strDialogueFileTitle)

'~~> Exits If No File Selected
If strWorkbookNameAndPath = "" Then
    MsgBox ("No Filename Selected")
    strCancel = "Y"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf strWorkbookNameAndPath = "False" Then
    MsgBox ("You Clicked The Cancel Button")
    strCancel = "Y"
    Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open strWorkbookNameAndPath


'~~> This declares path where the Individual forms will be saved.
foldertosavepath = "C:\File path\Forms\"

With wsSource
    '~~> Counts how many rows are in the Indication Tool
    lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lrow < 18 Then MsgBox "No data for transfer": Exit Sub
    For i = 18 To lrow
        Set wbForm = Workbooks.Open(formpath) '~~> open the form
        Set wsForm = wbForm.Sheets("Processing Form") '~~> Declare which worksheet to activate
        '~~> Proceed with the copying
        .Range("B" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("F7:K7")
        .Range("C" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("D8")
        .Range("C" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("D30")
        .Range("D" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("H29")
        .Range("E" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("E29")
        .Range("F" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("D33")
        .Range("G" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("J30:K30")
        .Range("H" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("P33")
        .Range("I" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("L33:N33")
        .Range("L" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("H32")
        .Range("R" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("D87")
        .Range("C2:F2").Copy wsForm.Range("J101:M101")
        .Range("C3:M3").Copy wsForm.Range("E102:O102")
        '~~> Save the form using the client name
        wbForm.SaveAs foldertosavepath & .Range("B" & i).Value & ".xls"
        '~~> These steps are for formatting, as I haven't figured out how paste values only
        Set wbForm = Workbooks.Open(formpath)
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        wsForm.Activate
        '~~> This allows the format to be pasted into the updated Form
        wsForm.Unprotect
        Cells.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        wsForm.Protect
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        wbForm.Close ([SaveChanges:=False])
        Set wbForm = Nothing
        Set wsForm = Nothing
   Next
End With

End Sub
```

When I debug the error, `Sub CopyToForm()` is highlighted in yellow and `strCancel =` is selected. Is there a way to set the user-chosen file as the formpath? Thanks in advance for your help, this has been a thorn in my side for quite some time.

Comment: Dim strCancel as string? Option Explicit means you have to declares all your variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Option Explicit` is declared, and strCancel isn't declared as a variable.

Add `Dim strCancel As String` to your code

Comment: and also  all other variables like here `FileFilter:=strFilt,  FilterIndex:=intFilterIndex, Title:=strDialogueFileTitle`? which actually even not initialized...